# Knockout Sorting - Time Consuming Task

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using knockout.js - I need to sort an observableArray that is bound to HTML table. Click on column header will sort an array ASC or DESC - quite common task.

The problem is that sorting freezes the UI for about 5sec. I know that is is caused because JS is single threaded.

My question is - is there any workaround for time consuming knockout sorting? I mean how to display some Loader indicater or something like that?

Comment: Are you sorting the observableArray itself or do you get the actual array and sort that and then put it back into the observable?

Comment: How many records in the array? Maybe it would be better to sort them on a server and using paging?

Comment: problem "solved" - please take a look on my onw answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem "solved" - sorting array is actually quite fast. The problem is re-render HTML elements on page.

**Advice** for other users: sorting underlying JS array seems (but I didn't measure it) to be bit faster than sorting observable array, e.g.:

THIS IS FASTER:

```
anObsArray().sort(--sorting func here--); // notice brackets after name of anObsArray
anObsArray().valueHasMutated(); // <-- this line is important
```

THAN THIS:

```
anObsArray.sort(--sorting func here--);
```